# Seeking automated approach for categorising roads according to their designs using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geometry, road

I have a shapefile comprised of polylines. The road segments are represented by lines that are between nodes. I want to categorise each road segment accordingly as they appear either as a straight road, curvilinear road or a road with single (or multiple) blind turning(s).

[image]

I want to refrain from using a visual approach when categorising these segments because its labour intensive, and such approach is subjective which may introduce some form of misclassification bias.

I was wondering if there is an automated approach for performing this task in QGIS?

Comment: Do the straight segments only have two vertices? If not, how do you define straight, for example deviation distance from a straight line from start-endpoint

Comment: All segments have only two vertices. The nodes in the shared image represents the endpoints of a segment.

Comment: Not in your screenshot. For example bottom right is a curved line which must have more than two vertices.

Comment: @BERA Sorry - I want clarify that the points are on the map are there to represent the start and end point of a road. In terms of vertices - I can confirm that straight segments have only two vertices which are at their endpoints. As for segments that curves or bends - they have more than two vertices as you've highlighted.

Comment: You could possibly achieve this using a symbology expression. For example, something like `if(num_points( $geometry) = 2, '#21d314', '#e31a1c')` would show straight segments as green, all others as red. You could play around with the expression to try and fit your needs :)

Comment: Please decide which of ArcGIS and QGIS you wish to ask about in this particular question.  You can always ask about the the other in a separate question.

Comment: @Joseph thank you very much, the shared code worked. I've managed to differentiate lines that are straight or lines that are curvilinear or have a single/multiple turnings (i.e. sharp or blind turn). Is there away to capture lines have a sharp turn? An example of this is a road segment that turns at a right-angle.

Comment: @The-PhD-Gamer - I think that would be quite difficult using just existing expressions. There is the `angle_at_vertex` function which returns the bisector angle at a specific vertex index. This should be simple for straight lines as the vertex index would be 1 but wouldn't be useful if the line contained more vertices.

Comment: You could compare the angle at each vertex to the angle of a (theoretical) line from the start vertex to the end vertex.